# What's the simplest way to do an operation in a background thread for an Activity?

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm sure this question gets asked a lot, but I'm looking for the simplest solution with Android best practices in mind (no hacky manifest that tries to keep a single Activity instance). Also, I'm not looking for a retain `Fragment` solution.

I'm looking for the simplest way in an `Activity` to initiate a background task and provide a callback function. If the `Activity` gets re-created (config change), then I want the old activity to release the reference, and attach a callback to the new Activity instance.

Lastly, I don't want to have to perform the operation again. Meaning, if it's some HTTP resource, it should be cached so that the operation is not run again wastefully.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you to use a static `WeakReference` on your subclass of `AsyncTask`. And update it according to the `Activity` lifecycle. Don't forget to check for null reference.

Comment: and a non-AsyncTask task solution? given that it's now deprecated in favor of loaders.

Comment: `AsyncTask` is most certainly not deprecated, let alone in favor of loaders. You might also consider explaining why you do not like a retained fragment in this case.

Comment: You're right @CommonsWare, it's not deprecated so much as the Android team is pushing the use of loaders. Also, I don't want to have to create a Fragment everytime I want to do a simple network request. There's many ways to skin a cat, but as the title indicates I am looking for the simplest solution. It would be nice to be able to create a simple Activity that can do a simple Restful API call and populate the view without having to re-run that background task on device rotate. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to decouple a task execution and activities(UI). To achieve this you can use events which UI sends to some `task executor`. The basic idea looks like this:

1. when method `onResume` was called you register you activity to receive events.
2. then later somewhere you execute the task to load some data from network.
3. next you have three options:

   - a) the task finished and your activity exists. The task sends event "i'm_finished". And your activity receives it.
   - b) the task is finished but your activity was destroyed/hided. When activity was hided the system called `onStop` method of your activity where you unregister your activity to receive new event. So event was not delivered.
   - c) the task is not finished and new activity was created. New activity checks if data is available or is downloading now in `onResume` method. If it's downloaded then show it, if not then wait.

The detailed explanation is here: http://www.mdswanson.com/blog/2014/04/07/durable-android-rest-clients.html.

The most popular event libraries for Android: [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) and [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Answer (score 0):

I my experience the simplest way is actually to use an AsyncTask (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). However, that might blow up after a config change. So you should probably attach that AsyncTask to a "HeadlessFragment". For the Fragment you can enable "setRetainInstanceState" so the fragment will not be recreated. Then after config change you can just attach to that fragment again.

Comment: Sorry, another idea, just after finishing that post: You might also attach an AsyncTask to you Application Class. That's a feature hardly used in an Android app, from my experience, but very useful. Some info can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html